# Looking for an "Erase to the Left" symbol for use with Windows Phone 7 Project

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm looking for an "Erase to the Left" font/character for use with Windows Phone 7 Project. Below is an image of what I'm looking for. Does anyone know if there is a way to use this Character in a WP7 project as a font? I'm looking to avoiding using it as a graphic but I cant find the character in the list of available fonts. I'm just hoping I'm missing something. I'm looking to use it on a button. It's the same one Microsoft uses in its Calculator app.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you check the Unicode character `U+232B ERASE TO THE LEFT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an icon to match this (if you <del>flip it</del> use the reflected horizontal ones) in  the awesome Windows Phone Icons set by @Templarian: http://templarian.com/project_windows_phone_icons/

http://templarian.com/files/wp_icons/icons/light/appbar.clear.inverse.png

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the question is a bit confusing. Using a character "as a font"?  "...looking for a 'Delete Character' font..."?  I think you might be asking is if any of the available fonts contains this graphic (as a character)?  If so, I'm reasonably certain that the answer is "no".  For one thing, the graphic is too large to be represented by a character.  As @Matt Lacey indicates, what you've posted here is an icon, not a character.

The list of available fonts in Windows Phone (unless Mango brings in additional ones) can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806365%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

If you can find some character that corresponds to what you want in any of these fonts, then fine, but I don't think you will.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my post. But I think your right none the less. I cant find that character in any of the available fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I did my own quick version of this symbol in Expression Blend - it's not perfect but is a Path you can use so you can change the Stroke Colour etc.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" 
Data="M15.673913,1 L46,1 L46,31 L15.673913,31 L1,15.758064 z M37.624989,8.375 L23.089996,22.91 M23.090002,8.375 L37.624996,22.91"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a delete character. Use the standard dustbin/trash can icon as this is the standard delete icon on the platform. If you use this then your users will instantly know what it means. If you use a non-standard icon, at best, you risk confusing your users.

A version of this icon ships with the SDK:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons\dark\appbar.delete.rest.png"

[image]